# Move shared vertices together

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features

I should move some vertices of a polygon to fix the boundaries of a country, how can I do it while keeping the adjacent polygons still connected? Is there a way to anchor permanently  overlapped vertices of adjacent polygons?

I'm using Qgis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Settings -> Snapping Options`,

Check the box that says `Enable Topoloogical Editing`

Now you can move the shared vertices together.